# Chrome bookmarks

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, memory, bookmarks

My personal computer crashed irreparably due to hardware issues, and as a consequence, I have lost access to all my chrome bookmarks. One of those bookmarks (the most important one, in fact), contained the URL to an overleaf paper of immense importance to me. I am not able to recover this data from my computer's memory, and neither can I obtain the aforementioned URL from my Google account.

Are the bookmarks stored somewhere in my computer's memory? I.e.if I recover the memory, will the links be there somewhere?

Comment: Did you ever back up the bookmarks ? Do you have the original hard drive? What operating system is this? Did you ever take a system back up?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, unlikely.

I will assume you didn't, for whatever reason, take back ups. Now think, you should have taken a back up. And from now on, take back ups. Things like Google Drive, Drop Box etc offer some free storage so use it!

I will assume you didn't use Chrome Sync.

I will also assume your on Windows OS (Vista or above).

Chrome saves your bookmarks every time you start Chrome

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Or if you every took a back up by going to Bookmark manager, Export then you can repeat the process but choose Import

If you still have the original hard drive you *may* be able to use a program to recover them. Programs like RECUVA may suffice for your needs, if not, Google/Bing `recover files OS` (replace OS with your operating system)

The file you want is called `bookmarks`

If you find this file with the recovery software, simply add it the directory shown above

Comment: I never backed them up because my laptop was practically brand new, and it didn't even occur to me that it might die this fast.

I do have the original hard drive and I use(d) Windows 7. 

Thank you very much for your help! I really hope this will work.

Comment: @Mehmeti, always back up! And then back up! And remember a back up doesn't mean copying a file to a new location, it means having 2 versions of that file in different places! :) Try Recuva if you have another PC to slave the old hard drive to . If not, most IT shops will be able to do this for you